# Deleting files with PowerShell

Tags: powershell

In the code below I am trying to have files older than 90 days be deleted from a powershell folder.  It will delete files older than 90 days, however if I have a subfolder in the powershell folder the files older than 90 days in the subfolder will be deleted as well. Why does this happen with the code below?

```
Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\powershell" -Recurse | Where-Object {($_.LastWriteTime -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-90))} | Remove-Item
```

Comment: It happens because you specifically asked `Get-ChildItem` to fetch them with `-Recurse`. Change the first command to `Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\powershell" -File` instead

Answer (score 2):

Mathias nailed it first go...

```
Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\powershell" -File | Where-Object {($_.LastWriteTime -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-90))} | Remove-Item
```

`-Recurse` is only if you need to work through subdirectories below your target, remove that and just use `-File` and it will only look for files in the target directory. Enjoy!